# How to make div tags expand to content when one drops below the other

Tags: css, html

I'm currently making a CSS layout and I have divs side by side in the main content. When the page is resized one drops below the other. When this happens I want the top div to take up the width of the parent div

```
#MainWrapper #Content {
float: left;
background-color:#E4E4E4;
width:100%;
max-width:1180px;
clear:left;
font-family: Bebas;
}
#Welcometext {
max-width: 500px;
min-width: 100%;
background-color:#399;
display:inline-block;
}
#Slideshow {
width: 100px;
background-color:#C96;
min-width: 200px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the html? thanks!

Comment: <div id="Welcometext"><p>Content for  id "Welcometext" Goes Here i4wjt wti wtoi wtoi qeroitjqweopr qwerhqwoehrqwoer hqweoir qwher qwoeir hqwor wqe rhqwe rqwioer hqwioe rqwe rhqwioer qwoeir qwerhi wqoierh qwoier hqwei rqwe r</p></div>
    <div id="Slideshow">Content for  id "Slideshow" Goes Here</div>
  </div>

Comment: That text was just to expand the div

Comment: Is it the #Slideshow that drops and needs to take on the width of the parent?

Comment: No the welcometext, When the browser is resized there is a gap to the right of the div. I want to to expand so it looks ok on mobile devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last comment, I think you want to look into @ media queries.

You can tell it to change specific properties when the width of the window drops below your specified width.

```
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    #Welcometext{
    Properties specific to to a screen size under 600px;
    }
  }
```

[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)